# block_admin_display_form_submit not getting called

Tags: 7, blocks

I am having trouble saving my block regions(admin/structure/blocks).

**Problem:**
I am doing my thing on block admin page, saving blocks, moving them around and what not. but the changes i make are not being saved.

**What i found:** after some debugging efforts, i figure out that the function *block_admin_display_form_submit* is not called when the block form submits.

the site i am having problem is on a lamp server somewhere. i have another copy of this site on my local machine, which has no problem saving block regions.

any idea on how to fix this? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, I cannot call function [block_admin_display_form_submit($form, &$form_state)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.admin.inc/function/block_admin_display_form_submit/7).

I've set a custom variable that should be updated if I change block region.

Everything works if I do it from the block edit page(admin/structure/block/manage/menu_block/ID/configure), but if I try to do it in the block admin display form (admin/structure/block), It will not work.

I've tried to increase max_input_vars with no success.

Have you solved it?

Comment: i fixed it by increasing max_input_vars.

Comment: I've managed to make it work. I was not calling the function in the proper way. Btw, I had already increased max_input_vars previously and I have tried to decrease it yet. I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: I can confirm it. It works without max_input_vars incresed. It's an Ubuntu server 12.04. In my php.ini I've got - ;max_input_vars=1000.